# how to print char on the screen

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I try to make '#' left side of the screen and the other side will be '$' but it's not stop on 25*40

```
.MODEL TINY

.CODE

.STARTUP

  CLD
  MOV AX, 0B800H ;for open screen
  MOV ES, AX    
  MOV DI, 0
  MOV CX, 25*40  ;try to divide screen 
  MOV AX, 5C23H
  REP STOSW

  MOV AX, 0B800H
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV SI,0  
  MOV CX, 25*40
  MOV AX, 6F24H
  REP STOSW

.EXIT
END
```

Comment: You are not setting the registers properly in the second part of your code. Do you want to split the screen *vertically* or *horizontally*? Because only the latter can be achieved with a continuous write to memory, the former must be implemented as 25 separate runs.

Comment: Why do you set `ds` to `b800`? Why do you set `si` to `0`? Looks like you put some random instructions into code and then see what will happen. Try it other way around, define what you want to happen, then write instructions which do exactly that.

Comment: i try to split screen vertically but it's not stop on 40. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Understand the video memory layout. It's going row by row, so first 80 bytes are first 40 characters on left (one character is 2 bytes: ASCII char + color attribute). Next 80 bytes are the remaining 40 characters forming first line. At address `B800:00A0` (+160 in decimal) starts second line. So you want to `rep stosw` 40 times the `0x5C23`, then 40 times `0x6F24` (80 words total = single line), and do that 25 times (for 25 lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.MODEL TINY

.CODE
.STARTUP

  CLD
  MOV AX, 0B800H ;for open screen
  MOV ES, AX
  XOR DI, DI     ; DI = 0
  MOV DX, 25     ; lines counter
line_loop:
  MOV CX, 40
  MOV AX, 5C23H
  REP STOSW
  MOV CX, 40
  MOV AX, 6F24H
  REP STOSW
  DEC DX
  JNZ line_loop

.EXIT
END
```

---

For fun and to exercise the power of `xor` for you, shorter variant of code (try to step over it in debugger or head and understand how it works):

```
  ...
  XOR DI, DI     ; DI = 0
  MOV DX, 50     ; 50 half-lines to fill
  MOV AX, 5C23H  ; start with '#'
half_line_loop:
  MOV CX, 40
  REP STOSW
  XOR AX, 3307h  ; 5C23 xor 3307 = 6F24, 6F24 xor 3307 = 5C23
  DEC DX
  JNZ half_line_loop
  ...
```

Comment: Thank u so much and i have a question , why did u do 'XOR DI,DI '

Comment: @muco because I want to set `di` to `0`, and I don't care about flags at that point of code, so I can use `xor "self"` instead of  `mov target,0`. The `xor` opcode is shorter (`31 FF = xor di,di`), as it doesn't have to encode the `0` number (`BF 00 00 = mov di,0`). Only difference is, that `xor` will affect also flags (in this case ZF=1 as result is `0`, CF=OF=SF=0).

Comment: @muco and if you don't know why `xor "self"` results into `0`, then read about bitwise operators: or/and/xor/not, how they work. They are sometimes very handy, especially for single bit manipulation in value composed from several independent bits (often used as "flags"). The "set to zero" by xor is sort of trick.

Comment: @muco I added second variant of code just to show you different way to achieve the same result. As with everything in ASM, you have many possible ways how to achieve particular result, that's why it is important to have clear idea what is the result you want, then write instructions to get to it. It doesn't make sense to memorize instructions from examples, but you have to understand what they do, and how.